# Join lines with the same value in the first column

Tags: bash, awk

I have a tab-delimited file with three columns (excerpt):

```
AC147602.5_FG004    IPR000146   Fructose-1,6-bisphosphatase class 1/Sedoheputulose-1,7-bisphosphatase
AC147602.5_FG004    IPR023079   Sedoheptulose-1,7-bisphosphatase
AC148152.3_FG001    IPR002110   Ankyrin repeat
AC148152.3_FG001    IPR026961   PGG domain
```

and I'd like to get this using bash:

```
AC147602.5_FG004 IPR000146 Fructose-1,6-bisphosphatase class 1/Sedoheputulose-1,7-bisphosphatase IPR023079 Sedoheptulose-1,7-bisphosphatase
AC148152.3_FG001 IPR023079 Sedoheptulose-1,7-bisphosphatase IPR002110   Ankyrin repeat IPR026961    PGG domain
```

So if ID in the first column are the same in several lines, it should produce one line for each ID with all other parts of lines joined. In the example it will give two-row file.

Comment: @oberlies, it is sometimes OK to add tags to a question that cover technologies used in answers, but not mentioned in the question.  This would be one of those cases, especially when the alternative is creating new meta tags.

Comment: @close-voters: How can this question be too broad? The answer is a one-line awk script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

give this one-liner a try:

```
 awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '{x=$1;$1="";a[x]=a[x]$0}END{for(x in a)print x,a[x]}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, the awk solution does not work for me in cygwin. So I used Perl instead. It joins around a tab character and separates line by \n

```
cat FILENAME | perl -e 'foreach $Line (<STDIN>) { @Cols=($Line=~/^\s*(\d+)\s*(.*?)\s*$/); push(@{$Link{$Cols[0]}}, $Cols[1]); } foreach $List (values %Link) { print join("\t", @{$List})."\n"; }'
```

Answer (score 0):

will depend off file size (and awk limitation)

if too big this will reduce the awk need by sorting file first and only keep 1 *label* in memory for printing

A classical version with post print using a modification of the whole line

```
sort YourFile \
 | awk '
      last==$1 { sub( /^[^[:blank:]]*[[:blank:]]+/, ""); C = C " " $0; next}
      NR > 1 { print Last C; Last = $1; C = ""}
      END { print Last}
      '
```

Another version using field and pre-print but less "*human readable*"

```
sort YourFile \
 | awk '
      last!=$1 {printf( "%s%s", (! NR ? "\n" : ""), Last=$1)}
      last==$1 {for( i=2;i<NF;i++) printf( " %s", $i)}
      '
```

Answer (score 0):

A pure bash version. It has no additional dependencies, but requires bash 4.0 or above (2009) for associative array support.

All on one line:

```
{ declare -A merged; merged=(); while IFS=$'\t' read -r key value; do merged[$key]="${merged[$key]}"$'\t'"$value"; done; for key in "${!merged[@]}"; do echo "$key${merged[$key]}"; done } < INPUT_FILE.tsv
```

Readable and commented equivalent:

```sh
{
  # Define `merged` as an empty associative array.
  declare -A merged
  merged=()

  # Read tab-separated lines. Any leftover fields also end up in `value`.
  while IFS=$'\t' read -r key value
  do
    # Append to any value that's already there, separated by a tab.
    merged[$key]="${merged[$key]}"$'\t'"$value"
  done

  # Loop over the input keys. Note that the order is arbitrary;
  # pipe through `sort` if you want a predictable order.
  for key in "${!merged[@]}"
  do
    # Each value is prefixed with a tab, so no need for a tab here.
    echo "$key${merged[$key]}"
  done
} < INPUT_FILE.tsv
```