# Reshuffling of specific structure file with bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I would appreciate your advice on how to deal with the following problem using Linux bash scripts.

I have a file with the following structure:

```
abc qwe, rty, 23er
abc ex6, 56789 45768, ew, fgcv
abc dfd, fghfghgf
d-e2 ghjkfg, 34
d-e2 opuo2rr
d-e2 56 rt-y, rggg, 1 9
```

It must be turned to:

```
abc, qwe, rty, 23er, ex6, 56789 45768, ew, fgcv, dfd, fghfghgf
d-e2, ghjkfg, 34, opuo2rr, 56 rt-y, rggg, 1 9
```

Put it simply, all lines starting with the same leading word («abc» and «d-e2» in my example) must be combined into single line. The leading words are separated from the rest with tabulation symbols, other records are separated with commas; each record may consist of a few words separated with multiple spaces which are to be preserved in converting.

I would try to invent something using some combination of sed or awk, grep and while myself, but as the file is big enough (contains a bit less than one million of lines), so effectiveness of the solution is of essence and I have only rudimentary knowing of bash scripting. A solution with Perl or Python or whatever would be great too, but I'd like to use this to gain some more knowledge of bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here i guess:
[Join lines with the same value in the first column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19823941/join-lines-with-the-same-value-in-the-first-column)
There is a cute AWK one-liner inside, which should be working for you as well.

Moreover i think that u should try to write more specific topic- not only "sorting file with specific structure" but something more  concrete like in the example above.
cheers.

Comment: A few modifications are needed.: `sed 's/, /,/g;s/ /,/' file | awk -F',' -v OFS=', ' '{x=$1;$1="";a[x]=a[x]$0}END{for(x in a)print x a[x]}'`

Comment: Thank you both. That one-liner solves my issue, especially the variant modified by Cyrus.

@Dominik. Yeah, you're right. Will try to be more specific next time.