# Find the occurrences of different versions of a file

Tags: shell

I've got a couple of hundred files that may all be the same, or there may be two or more variants.  I'd like to compare them all, and produce some sort of report on how many versions there are, and which ones are the same as each other.  I imagine output something like:

```
versionA: file1, file3, file137
versionB: file2, file16
...
```

or

```
file1: versionA
file2: versionB
file3: versionA
...
```

...but really anything that more-or-less accomplishes the same thing would be fine.

I'm a linux person stuck on a Windows box, so Powershell works, but I've got cygwin and most of the usual bash/linux toolbox to work with as well.  I could imagine hacking together some monstrous recursive diff -s of every file with every other, but it seems like there ought to be a better way.

Comment: md5sum + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19823941/join-lines-with-the-same-value-in-the-first-column ?

Comment: To be on-topic here, you need to focus on a narrow, specific technical problem you ran into while doing this work yourself. (Also, it's not clear how we're supposed to determine what's a version of fileA, vs a version of fileB, etc; the file's basename? edit distance? something else?)

Comment: that said, for a lot of this I'd think about relying on a version control system under the hood. a lot of git's plumbing, f/e, exists to efficiently decide which files are similar enough to other files to constitute a different version of them, vs a completely new file.

Comment: Fair point.  I was going with "file contents differ in any way" as the definition of "different", which makes KamilCuk's suggestion of md5sum exactly the obvious answer that I should have seen myself.  The linked awk stuff isn't even necessary; "md5sum * | sort" does what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[KamilCuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamilcuk) said it in a comment, but I'll make an answer out of it just so I can mark this as solved:

```
md5sum * | sort
```

Thanks,